# How receive binary data in multiple frames in go lang

Tags: go, websocket

I successfully sent file data in the `form` of a frame to the `websocket`. I can split file data in multiple frames and send to `websocket`, but i don't know how to receive and merge frames in one data array.

I gonna do this for getting progress of sending file to websocket:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "io/ioutil"
    ...
    ...
)
...
...
var data []byte
err = websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &data)
if (err == nil) {
    ioutil.WriteFile("/home/img.jpg", data, 0644)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it should be unnecessary to split data into multiple frames and then merge them.

If you want to get progress, maybe the `func (ws *Conn) Read(msg []byte) (n int, err error)` can be called with a relatively small buffer size. So you don't read the whole message in one go. But you may have to always send the file size before file content. (e.g. first 8 bytes is always the file size, and file content starts from the 9th.) So you can use `sumOfReceivedSize / fileSize` to show the progress after each call of `Read`.

---

If you want to split file data no matter what:

Simply send the file size in the first message (as first 8 bytes), and then send all the rest chunks in separate messages.

Multiple messages will be received, until the recipient gets enough data, i.e. reaches the file size.

Comment: it might be nesessary if we would work with images of 10+GB size like in medicine diagnostics

Comment: I can send on big message (file data bytes) but how can get progress (percent) of sending file without splitting in multiple frames?

Comment: be careful, moderators like to move long conversations in chatrooms. better practise - edit main question with details.